# Object in D3 Donut

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know how I can use an array with [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js)donuts but I can't seem to understand how objects work with [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js).

I'd like to output the following object:

**Code**

```
var width = 175,
  height = 175,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  donutWidth = 23;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
var data = [{
    user: 'Bob',
    value: 100
  },
  {
    user: 'Danny',
    value: 200
  }
];

function render(data) {
  //data = [100,250];
  var svg = d3.select("#pot").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  var svg_g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null);
  var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
    .outerRadius(radius);
  var path = svg_g.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(data));
  var pathEnter = path.enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(i);
    })
    .attr("d", arc)
  var pathUpdate = path.attr("d", arc);
}

render(data);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om4fm4jt/1/)

I'd like the values from the object to be rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to show the values in the donut you should add:

`.value(function(d) { return d.value })` at `var pie = d3.pie()`.

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var width = 175,
    height = 175,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    donutWidth = 23;
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
  var data = [{
    user: 'Bob',
    value: 100
  }, {
    user: 'Danny',
    value: 200
  }, {
    user: 'Test',
    value: 50
  }];

  function render(data) {
    var svg = d3.select("#pot").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
    var svg_g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
        return d.value
      })
      .sort(null);
    var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
      .outerRadius(radius);
    var path = svg_g.selectAll("path")
      .data(pie(data));
    var pathEnter = path.enter().append("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
      })
      .attr("d", arc)
    var pathUpdate = path.attr("d", arc);
  }
  render(data);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="pot"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, I even tried something similar to this, thanks for the help! Works like a charm!